# I'm trying to update a key in a dictionary by adding a number to the already existing key

Tags: python, dictionary, math

Basically I am attempting to create a program that holds and updates employee's work hours by asking for their employee ID and how many hours they worked that day, and then adding their new work hours to their already existing hours.

I keep the employee ID's and work hours in a dictionary, called hours_logged.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TPbe.png)

My problem is that when I try to mutate the key value by doing hours_logged[employee_ID] = hours_logged[employee_ID] + todays_hours. Except this doesn't work. How do I do addition within a dictionary?

Expected: employee hours are added up, and continue to add up and save to the dictionary
Actual: I get a warning that I cannot add int and str. (even though when I ask for the input for a key, I make sure it's an integer.)

Comment: Show the relevant code properly formatted in the question, especially how "todays_hours" is set.

Comment: entry = input('Enter employee ID: ')
    if entry in hours_logged:
        new_hours = int(input('Log hours here: '))
        hours_logged[entry] = int(hours_logged[entry]) + int(new_hours)
```
`

The error I get is that I can't make a string an integer? please help! not sure where to go from here

Comment: Show it properly formatted **in the question**, not as comment.

Comment: done! sorry about that I am very new to stackoverflow. Thank you SO much.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full code that produces the error. There is no reason that `hours_logged[employee_ID] = hours_logged[employee_ID] + todays_hours` should produce an error if `hours_logged[employee_ID]` and `todays_hours` are both `int`, so obviously one of them is not.

Comment: (1) Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first. (2) Show your code as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link. (3) Show the code that creates "todays_hours".

Answer (score 0):

Either `hours_logged[employee_ID]` is currently a string, or `todays_hours` is a string.

`todays_hours` is easy to check, since you must be casting it to int before addition.

`hours_logged[employee_ID]` could be a string if you initialized it with `"0"` for every employee somewhere at the beginning. Check that part and cast it to int.

You could also forcibly cast everything to int like this `hours_logged[employee_ID] = int(hours_logged[employee_ID]) + int(todays_hours)`. It would be better to still figure out where this string is coming from.

Comment: I am trying to make a code that updates employee hours. I get a variety of errors when I try and update the value that is holding the employee's current hours.
`
```
entry = input('Enter employee ID: ')
    if entry in hours_logged:
        new_hours = int(input('Log hours here: '))
        hours_logged[entry] = int(hours_logged[entry]) + int(new_hours)
```
`

The error I get is that I can't make a string an integer? please help! not sure where to go from here

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. Either you are entering hours as not a single number, but something like "25 hours". Or it actually complains about some other place in your code. For example, where you try to convert `entry` to int.